# Leaderboard command discord.py: How to order members from greatest level to least?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

So in my discord bot there is a leveling system, and I want to make a leaderboard command to see the top 5 users. I'm using an sqlite3 db to store the users' levels. How would I make a leaderboard command and a rank command in which the user just gets his/her own rank?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used much SQLite, but normally a query like this would work:

```sql
SELECT FROM table_name    
ORDER BY column_name DESC   /* Change the table and column name accordingly */
LIMIT 5
```

You can then format the output somehow